# How to generate a list of strings from a single string with seperators?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want to achieve the following:

Given: A string like `'path1.path2.path3'`;

Wanted result: A list of strings -> `[path1, path1.path2, path1.path2.path3]`;

The order has to be the same, I just need all the "levels". I need this to create a breadcrumb-component for an Angular-Applikation using ui-router. States do have names like "path1.path2", which means path2 is a child of path1.

The problem for me is not the splitting, I know how to achieve that via split. My problem is merging them again like mentioned above.

My first idea was to use **array.split** to get the single parts of the string. But I'm not sure how to build the loop to add a single partial in each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this does what you want:

```js
'path1.path2.path3'
  .split('.')
  .map((section, i, arr) => [...arr.slice(0, i), section].join('.'));
```

It splits the strings into sections using `.` as the delimiter, then for each section, it joins it together with all previous sections, using `.` as the delimiter.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I also found a solution which looks a lot more complicated than yours:

        this.breadcrumb = this.router.globals.current.data.breadcrumb; // path1.path2.path3
        this.breadCrumbPartials = this.breadcrumb.split('.'); // [path1,path2,path3]
        this.stateList = [];
     
        let state = '';
        for(let i = 0; i < this.breadCrumbPartials.length; i++) {
            if(i > 0) {
                state = state + '.';
            }
            
            state = state + this.breadCrumbPartials[i];

            this.stateList.push(state);
        }

Answer (score 1):

Try using a reducer for the splitted string. Something like:

```js
const str = "path1.path2.path3";

console.log( str.split(".").reduce( (acc, str, i) => 
  [...acc, (i ? `${acc[i - 1]}.${str}` : str)], []) );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already some answers here, but i'd like to add mine with reduce:

```js
const string = 'path1.path2.path3'

const paths = string.split('.')

const res = paths.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, `${acc[acc.length-1] ? acc[acc.length-1] + '.' : ''}${curr}`], [])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the position of the dots and slice the array.

```js
const
    string = 'path1.path2.path3',
    result = [];

let p = string.indexOf('.');

while (p !== -1) {
    result.push(string.slice(0, p));
    p = string.indexOf('.', p + 1);
}

result.push(string);

console.log(result);
```